# Displaying results of multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, backend

I am making two API calls to a backend server and I am using the following approach to display both responses in json to the user. However, **alert 2 is 'undefined'** according to console; and alert 1 works. What am I doing wrong?

```
app.get("/blah", function (req, res) {

    var alert = 'api call for alert' 
    var alert2 = 'api call for alert 2' 


    request(alert, alert2, function (error, response, alert, alert2) { 

        console.log(alert); 
        console.log(alert2);

        res.json({
            Alert: alert,
            Alert2: alert2
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because request does not allow multiple requests to be made asynchronously from one call in this way.

One way you could achieve this asynchronously is by using async.parallel from the async module.

However, for simplicity i'm just going to be providing an example that won't require the async module, but will instead work in a serial way.

**This is not the most efficient way of doing this as in your example the second request does not require the first request to be completed first.**

```
app.get("/blah", function (req, res) {

    var alert = 'api call for alert' 
    var alert2 = 'api call for alert 2' 

   request(alert, function (error, response, alert) { 

        console.log(alert);

        request(alert2, function (error, response, alert2) { 
            console.log(alert2);

            res.json({
                Alert: alert,
                Alert2: alert2
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Async example (https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
app.get("/blah", function (req, res) {

    var alert = 'api call for alert' 
    var alert2 = 'api call for alert 2'

    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            request(alert, function (error, response, alert) {
                if(error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    callback(null, alert);
                }
            });
        },

        function(callback) {
            request(alert2, function (error, response, alert2) {
                if(error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    callback(null, alert2);
                }
            });
        }
    ], function(err, results) {
        res.json({
            Alert: results[0],
            Alert2: results[1]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It generally is, but in this example as the second request is inside the callback of the first request it means that the first request must have been completed - hence it is blocked and isn't asynchronous.

Comment: I've added an async example

Comment: thank you but when I tried the first approach you provided and got an error: 'null' in the console for alert2

Comment: Can you console.log error for the alert2 reqest? Are you sure that alert2 request should respond with something other than 'null'?

Comment: sorry I was away, your solution actually works, it turns out there was an error in the backend that gave a null exception. I will accept your answer